# How to "mash together" the contents of 2 hard drives?

Tags: hardware, lvm, hard-drive

Previous research suggests that I need an LVM.  However, I can't find anything for what to do about data being on *both* drives.  I took the hard drive of an existing, running 10.04 computer and put it into another existing, running, machine.  I want to be able to access the files like they were on the local(booting) hard drive.  For example, having the applications that were previously installed on the "foreign" drive accessible through the "Applications" button.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge the contents using a union mount, but this would not do what you want. All the system files from the new hard drive would mask the entire system on the boot hard disk, so you would effectively be trying to replace the whole operating system while it is running, not just the newly installed applications.

If you want to make the second system into a "clone" of the first, with all the same applications installed, you can use aptitude. First, you run [aptitude-create-state-bundle](http://manual.cream.org/index.cgi/usr/share/man/man1/aptitude-create-state-bundle.1) on the first system. This creates a record of all the applications you have installed. You copy this file to the second system, and then use [aptitude-run-state-bundle](http://manual.cream.org/index.cgi/usr/share/man/man1/aptitude-run-state-bundle.1) on it. This will install all those same applications on the second system.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's impossible, there is only one root fs (/). But you can always boot from your second drive, just run **sudo update-grub** while its connected.

Comment: Googling reveals update-grub will create a grub config file.  Please forgive my ignorance, but what does this do and how will it help me?

Comment: That's only for booting from second drive :)

Comment: Oh!  So I can't merge the contents, but I can just boot the other one(after **sudo grub-config**).  I think I understand now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because:
1) Changing from non LVM to LVM requires to rebuild your partitions (data loss)
2) You can not merge existing running systems, it would bring all the sort of problems like only keeping the package database from one system
You only option is to backup user data, reconfigure the diks with LVM and reinstall.